# Eclipse not opening; "Unresolved Requirement"

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been coding a small project in Java, and don't know what changed between today and last week, but for some reason my Eclipse is not opening, and the error log is giving a huge error message, which I can't paste most of here because of the character limit. Here is the beginning of the error message:

```
!SESSION 2017-06-25 21:09:24.945 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
java.version=1.6.0_65
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/meiragoldman/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/meiragoldman/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 4 0 2017-06-25 21:09:25.660
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.equinox.ds [133]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.event; version="1.0.0"
    -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.event; bundle-version="1.0.500.v20130404-1337"; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.equinox.util"; version="1.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.equinox.ds"
       org.eclipse.equinox.util [181]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.osgi.service.cm; version="1.0.0"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.event 4 0 2017-06-25 21:09:25.663
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.equinox.event [134]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.osgi.service.event; version="[1.3.0,1.4.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ant.ui 4 0 2017-06-25 21:09:25.670
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.ant.ui [57]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.externaltools; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.editors; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.editors; bundle-version="3.8.200.v20140401-1310"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui.editors [348]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="3.10.2.v20141118-1227"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.ui.ide [507]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="[3.106.0,4.0.0)"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.106.1.v20141002-1150"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.ui [506]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="[3.105.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                         -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="3.106.2.v20150204-1030"; singleton:="true"
                            org.eclipse.ui.workbench [511]
                              Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench
                                -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench; bundle-version="1.2.2.v20141212-1259"; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.fragment,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt,  org.eclipse.ui.workbench"
                                   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench [471]
                                     Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.services; bundle-version="0.9.0"
                                       -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.ui.services; bundle-version="1.1.0.v20140328-1925"; singleton:="true"
                                          org.eclipse.e4.ui.services [94]
                                            Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.osgi.service.event; resolution:="optional"
                                            Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.di; bundle-version="0.9.0"
                                              -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.ui.di; bundle-version="1.0.0.v20140328-2112"
                                                 org.eclipse.e4.ui.di [92]
                                                   Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions; bundle-version="0.9.0"
                                                     -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions; bundle-version="0.12.0.v20140417-2033"; singleton:="true"
                                                        org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions [86]
                                                          Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.osgi.services; bundle-version="3.2.100"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="3.10.2.v20141118-1227"; singleton:="true"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor; bundle-version="3.9.0.v20140411-1521"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor [363]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.106.1.v20141002-1150"; singleton:="true"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.views; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.views; bundle-version="3.7.0.v20140408-0703"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui.views [359]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.106.1.v20141002-1150"; singleton:="true"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Comment: Removed tags from title; grammar; noise reduction.

Answer (score -1):

As per [this thread](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/823236/) the answer is:

```
I took the first class reporting the error, 

i.e. org.eclipse.osgi 

and deleted the (lock) files under under configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.manager

Files had names starting with .fileTable

I was then able to start Eclipse without a computer reboot but did have to specify the workspace when it restarted.
```

Just try this solution and It will work.

Comment: under this path configuration/org.eclipse.osgi all I see are a bunch of folders with numbers as names (ie 50, 57, 58...). And a framework.info.4 file. I dont see any lock files or anything starting with .filetable

Comment: this didn't work for me